# How to highlight text by using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pcregrep

I'm trying writing a script to help highlight when match with regex. Below is my example that what I do now.

```js
var text = "SOMETHING ~WEIRDs~ AND Not WEIRD";
var regexp = /\b(WEIRD)\b/
var matches = text.match(regexp);

for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  var replace_all = RegExp(matches[i] + "(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)", "ig");
  text = text.replace(eval(replace_all), "<span style='background-  color:yellow'>" + matches[i] + "</span>");
}
console.log(text);
```

The output of the code above is

```
SOMETHING ~<span style='background-  color:yellow'>WEIRD</span>s~ AND Not <span style='background-  color:yellow'>WEIRD</span>
```

The output I want is

```
SOMETHING ~WEIRDs~ AND Not <span style='background-  color:yellow'>WEIRD</span>
```

I would like to know is that anyway to write a regex contains regex and words provided? Or have any other method can solve this incorrect replace issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your outer regex is fine. The issue is with the inner `replace_all` regex in the loop , as it replaces all instances of the found string, no matter its position in the original string.

Instead use the original Regex with `replace()` using the matches within the replacement string, like this:

```js
var text = "SOMETHING ~WEIRDs~ AND Not WEIRD";
var regexp = /\b(WEIRD)\b/
var text = text.replace(regexp, '<span style="background-color: yellow">$1</span>');
console.log(text);
```

Also, as a general rule, never, ever use `eval()`. There is *always* a better solution or alternative.